# NetBeans: Android project to use external jar?

Tags: android, netbeans

I'm a fresher in Android(also Java and NetBeans) dev. :)
I've imported ksoap2 to handle WebServices staffs, it's fine when building the project, but failed to run in AVD, below is the exceptions segments:

> *E/dalvikvm(  353): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.iBest.Mobile.Login.authUser
>   W/dalvikvm(  353): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 88 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/iBest/Mobile/Login;
>   W/dalvikvm(  353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  353): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  353):    at com.iBest.Mobile.Login.authUser(Login.java:58)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  353):    at com.iBest.Mobile.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:47)*

I've put the `jar(ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar)` in folder `libs`

What else needed I do? thanks.

Comment: The project is writen in NetBeans, in which there is no Java Build Path item. I tried Project Properties in right context, there are four tabs: General, Libraries, Jar Libraries and Run, but no one works..

Comment: I search on internet, maybe it can be resolve by fix the build script to manually include the external jars into the Apk package, but I don't know how to do that. Any one can give me some clue?

Answer (score 0):

From your project make a reference to ksoap library. You can do that by right clicking on the project and properties. Select **Java Build Path** and **Add Jars**. Browse to the ksoap jar and select it.

Comment: The project is writen in NetBeans, in which there is no Java Build Path item. I tried Project Properties in right context, there are four tabs: General, Libraries, Jar Libraries and Run, but no one works..